# How do I use SQL to search a many to many relationship using AND

Tags: sql, many-to-many

Can anyone help to create a SQL code which could list movies which have been searched under 2 or more tags for the tables below? E.g. I want to list all movies which have the tags “4star” AND “Drama”.

[Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xlFD.jpg)

I have managed to create one which lists movies which have either one or another tag… thus.

```
Select tblMovies.MovieName 
FROM tblMovies, tblBridge, tblTags 
WHERE ((tblTags.TagID=1) OR (tblTags.TagID=5))
And tblTags.TagID = tblBridge.TagID 
And tblBridge.MediaID= tblMovies.MovieID
```

Which gives Star Wars, Aliens, Goodfellows, Mermaids.

But I'm struggling with the AND code which would give Goodfellows and The Godfather if I search for movies which have tags 1 (4star) and 7 (Drama) for example.

Many thanks.

Comment: Look for [JOIN](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-using-joins.htm) and [IN](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm) clauses

Comment: Are you learning SQL right now? Who then told you to use commas to join the tables? This is a syntax of the 1980s. Since 1992 standard SQL features explicit joins (`[INNER] JOIN`, `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN`, etc.). Please don't use commas in the `FROM` clause. This syntax is prone to errors and harder to read and maintain.

Comment: And please tag your request with the DBMS you are using. Always do this when asking SQL questions, because answers may heavily depend on your DBMS.

Comment: And [please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Copy and paste your table data as formatted text into your request instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for movies for which exist both tags 1 and 7. We don't use joins usually when we only want to check whether data exists. We use `EXISTS`. Or `IN`, which expresses the same thing (movies that are in the set of tag 1 movies and also in the set of tag 7 movies).

The idea is that we select `FROM` the table we want to see results from. And we use the `WHERE` clause to tell the DBMS which rows we want to see.

### With EXISTS

```
SELECT m.moviename
FROM tblmovies m
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT null FROM tblbridge b WHERE b.tagid = 1 AND b.movieid = m.movieid)
  AND EXISTS (SELECT null FROM tblbridge b WHERE b.tagid = 7 AND b.movieid = m.movieid)
ORDER BY m.moviename;
```

### With IN

```
SELECT m.moviename
FROM tblmovies m
WHERE m.movieid IN (SELECT b.movieid FROM tblbridge b WHERE b.tagid = 1)
  AND m.movieid IN (SELECT b.movieid FROM tblbridge b WHERE b.tagid = 7)
ORDER BY m.moviename;
```

I should add that these are not the only options available to get that result. But they are the straight-forward ones. (Another is conditional aggregation, but you'll learn this later.)